# Replace strings in one column based on two columns from another data frame

Tags: r, regex, string, replace

I have one column in a multi-column data frame, let's call that **df1**, that consists of some text, some example rows below:

```
"896 European ancestry cases, 2,455 European ancestry controls"
"591 European individuals, 687 European males"
"1,968 African American cases, 3,928 African American controls"
```

Then I have two columns in another data frame, let's call that **df2**, that look like this:

```
"European ancestry cases", "European"
"European ancestry controls", "European"
"European individuals", "European"
"European males", "European"
"African American cases", "African"
"African American controls", "African"
```

The quotation marks aren't actually there, I just used those to clarify the number of columns.

I would like to replace, in **df1**, all the instances of the first column of **df2** with the second column of **df2**. In other words, I want to change **df1** only, but using information in **df2**, which would give me back the following result:

```
"896 European, 2,455 European"
"591 European, 687 European"
"1,968 African, 3,928 African"
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this in R?

*(PS. The real data has thousands of rows for both **df1** and **df2**, with many more variations, these example rows are a simplification of the problem)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```r
# 1
gsub("(European|African)([^,]+)", "\\1", df1$txt)

# 2
gsub("(?<=European|African)[^,]+", "", df1$txt, perl = TRUE)

# [1] "896 European, 2,455 European"
# [2] "591 European, 687 European"  
# [3] "1,968 African, 3,928 African"
```

---

You could also use `str_replace_all()` from `stringr` to perform multiple replacements by passing a named vector (`c(pattern1 = replacement1)`) to it.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  mutate(txt = str_replace_all(txt, deframe(df2)))

#                            txt
# 1 896 European, 2,455 European
# 2   591 European, 687 European
# 3 1,968 African, 3,928 African
```

---

###### Data

```r
df1 <- data.frame(txt = c("896 European ancestry cases, 2,455 European ancestry controls",
                          "591 European individuals, 687 European males",
                          "1,968 African American cases, 3,928 African American controls"))

df2 <- structure(list(
V1 = c("European ancestry cases", "European ancestry controls", "European individuals", "European males", "African American cases", "African American controls"),
V2 = c("European", "European", "European", "European", "African", "African")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you! It runs fine on the example data, but when I run it on the real data (which has thousands of rows for both df1 and df2, with many variations), for some reason it removes most, if not all, spaces and all the instances of the letter "i". Strange, right?

Comment: @Abdel Maybe the regular expression syntax doesn't handle the variations of your real data. I think the `str_replace_all()` solution is more stable because it does exact matches. Have you tried it? If it still cannot work, you need to give me an instance it fails on.

Comment: I did mean the str_replace_all() solution, I didn't try the regular expression, because that would for sure not handle all the variation. One instance where it went wrong is "519 Japanese ancestry cases" was changed to "519East Asan", whereas it should have been changed to "519 East Asian", so it dropped the space and the "i". It seems to do this everywhere...

Comment: @Abdel That's because there exists leading whitespaces and typos in your `df2`. Please check the Japan part of your `df2`. The first column is `" Japanese ancestry"` and the second is `"Asan"`, right? So the problem results from your data, not my code. You need to remove the leading spaces of `df2` in advance(e.g. by `trimws()` function) before use my code.

Comment: There are no typos in df2, I am very certain of this. The first column of df2 says "Japanese ancestry cases" and the second says "East Asian". Also, it does not only do this for this example. It also changes "African" to "Afrcan", and there are many more examples. I'm not sure if it's your code, there could very well something else strange be going on as well of course, I'll try to figure it out! Thanks for your time!

Comment: You were right about the leading spaces, that did resolve the space issue, but it mysteriously still removes all the "i". I'll just patch that up afterwards, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I found the issue with the "i". One of the lines of df2 had "i" in the first column and nothing in the second... That is embarrassing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more:

```
#library(dplyr)
#library(stringr)
#library(tidyr)
#library(readr)
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(col1, sep = "\\, ") %>% 
  mutate(col1 = str_c(parse_number(col1), 
                      str_extract(col1, str_c(unique(df2$col2), collapse = "|")), sep = " ")) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(col1 = toString(col1)) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-id)
```

```
 col1                       
  <chr>                      
1 896 European, 2455 European
2 591 European, 687 European 
3 1968 African, 3928 African
```

data:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(col1 = c("896 European ancestry cases, 2,455 European ancestry controls", 
"591 European individuals, 687 European males", "1,968 African American cases, 3,928 African American controls"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
> dput(df2)
structure(list(col1 = c("European ancestry cases", "European ancestry controls", 
"European individuals", "European males", "African American cases", 
"African American controls"), col2 = c("European", "European", 
"European", "European", "African", "African")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```